# Accessing objects with same id

Tags: python, kivy

For the sake of reproducibility im reusing an object multiple times rather than creating a new one,

Im adding the Factory object into the main Layout and using the remove button i can remove the added object,

But if i add 2 or more objects into the Layout the remove function only works for the last added object

So is there any mechanism that can generate a unique id for an object which can be then used to delete it

Code

```
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.factory import Factory 

kv='''

<Image_1@BoxLayout>:

    orientation:'vertical'
    id:img_1   
    Image:
        source:"/storage/emulated/0/Download/download (37).jpeg"
    Button:
        text:"remove"
        on_press:app.remove()
    
 

BoxLayout:
    orientation:'vertical'
    
                        
    GridLayout:
        cols:1
        id:sc_grid
        
        Button:
            size_hint:None,None 
            text:"add"
            on_press:
                app.add_1()      
                              

'''

class MyApp(MDApp):
    
    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_string(kv)
    
    def add_1(self):
        self.Image_1=Factory.Image_1()
        self.root.ids.sc_grid.add_widget(self.Image_1)
    def remove(self):
        self.root.ids.sc_grid.remove_widget(self.Image_1)
        
MyApp().run()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what your app will do in the end but you could do it without an id.

By adding the remove handler to the `Image` object and access it with `self.parent.remove`. Alternatively, you could track your objects in a list to add/remove items.

For creating a UUID you could use Pythons `uuid.uuid4()` method but I think that's optional.

Please have a look at the below code which allows adding & removing items.

```py
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.factory import Factory 
import uuid

kv='''

<Image_1@BoxLayout>:

    orientation:'vertical'
    #id:img_1   
    Image:
        source:"/storage/emulated/0/Download/download (37).jpeg"
    Button:
        text:"remove"
        on_press: self.parent.remove()
    
 

BoxLayout:
    orientation:'vertical'
    
                        
    GridLayout:
        cols:1
        id:sc_grid
        
        Button:
            size_hint:None,None 
            text:"add"
            on_press:
                app.add()      
                              

'''

class MyApp(MDApp):
    
    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_string(kv)
    
    def add(self):
        Image=Factory.Image_1()
        # Image.id = uuid.uuid4()
        Image.remove = lambda: self.root.ids.sc_grid.remove_widget(Image)
        self.root.ids.sc_grid.add_widget(Image)
        
MyApp().run()
```

Comment: Cool ! , i better use the remove handler provided to the image object rather than using uuid